# Array Out of Bound Index Error

Tags: java

I am attempting to find the occurrence frequency of a number in a sequence.

for example when sequence is :

```
1, 1, 3, 4
```

output should be

```
1 found 3 times 
, 3 found 1 times 
, 4 found 1 time
```

and so on.  I have the following code

```
import java.util.*;

class fre {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int c = a.length;
        int d[] = new int[c];
        int num = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < c; p++)
            d[p] = Integer.parseInt(a[p]);
        for (int z : d)
            System.out.println(z);
        for (int i = 0; i < c - 1; i++)       // FROM THIS LINE ERROR IS THROWN
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < c - 1; i++) {
                if (d[i] == d[t]) {
                    num++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("the element" + i + "found" + num + "times");
        }
    }
}
```

> ERROR : ARRAY OUT OF BOUND INDEX

Comment: The ALL-CAPS really makes it stand out!

Comment: May I suggest using more useful variable names?

Comment: I run it in my IDE and it works normally

Comment: your name describes the way you code. outstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
for (int t = 0; t < c - 1; i++)
```

be

```
for (int t = 0; t < c - 1; t++)
```

You are incrementing `i` again in the second loop.

Comment: this make complete sense

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you increment i instead of t in the inner loop.
Changing this, the program seems to work.

Change the output line to sth. like

`System.out.println("the element " + d[i] + " found " + num + " times");`

To make it readable.

Not saying there is no better way to solve this...

ok
Benno

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an array that holds all the command line parameters. You are using `a.length` which determines the *amount of command line parameters given*. I guess you probably want to pass the length of the array by a command line parameter instead. If I am correct, you should use something like `int c = a[0];` to get the first command line parameter. Of course that is not good style without any checks, but if I get started on that I had to rewrite your whole code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong.

Untested:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

  for (String s : args) {
    Integer currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(s);
    // don't forget error handling if s is not a number
    Integer currentCount = result.get(currentNumber);
    if (currentCount == null) { // you could also check with result.containsKey(..)
      currentCount = 0;
    }
    result.put(currentNumber, currentCount + 1);
  }

  for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result) {
    System.out.println("The element: " + entry.getKey() + " found " + entry.getValue() +     " times");
  }
}
```

This is probably slower than your version, but easier to understand.

Comment: There are a few **very** common data structures in Java (and most other programming languages).

Comment: - Map: as the name suggests, this stores a map between values.  I think an example will explain this (otherwise just google for it):  
`Map<Integer, String> aMap = new HashMap<>();
// this is a map which "points" from Integers to Strings;
aMap.put(42, "the Answer .. Everything");
aMap.put(3, "three");
System.out.println(aMap.get(3)); // "three";
aMap.put(3, "drei");
System.out.println(aMap.get(3)); // "drei";
// the value "three" doesn't exist any longer;`

In my code I have a map from every Integer found to an Integer counter.